# Login failed for user in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server

When i want to run application on other computers in network the following error occurs:

> error : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user
>   'Suren-PC\Guest'.

Here is the connection string:

```
ConnectionStr = "Data Source=SUREN-PC\\MSSQLSERVER,1433;Initial Catalog=WorkFlow;Integrated Security=True";
```

Application has access to database when runs on the server computer.

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Comment: please show us what you tried to do.

Comment: I can't see login credentials in your conn string

Comment: check whatever login you are using is having access on DB or not

Comment: It uses windows authentication, so you should add those users to logins in that instanse.

Comment: It runs on the server only because you login with a different account there. Use *an actual domain account* on the PC, not the guest account and add it as a user to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to add new login add assign it to some role:

```
USE [master]
GO

CREATE LOGIN [Suren-PC\Guest] 
FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english]
GO

ALTER SERVER ROLE /*some role here*/ ADD MEMBER [Suren-PC\Guest]
GO
```

Alternatively you can do the same from management studio through wizard.

Comment: I doubt if this will work. The OP uses the desktop's Guest account instead of a normal domain account. Even if it were, using the `Guest` account is a bad security practice

Comment: Yes, it is just a code how to add login. He should decide which to add to which role etc

Comment: This isn't enough. You can't grant access to another computer's accounts to SQL Server. You'd need to use Workgroup authentication, which means creating accounts with identical names and passwords on the server. I would consider this a serious security smell